# chai reuse series of expects

Tags: javascript, node.js, chai

How do I reuse a series of expects? 
For example:

```
expect(savedUser).to.have.all.keys(['fbId', 'fbName', 'gender', 'birthdate', 'aboutMe']);
expect(savedUser.fbId).to.equal(u.fbId);
expect(savedUser.fbName).to.equal(u.fbName);
expect(savedUser.gender).to.equal(u.gender);
expect(savedUser.birthdate).to.equal(u.birthdate);
expect(savedUser.aboutMe).to.equal(u.aboutMe);
```

I want to verify these conditions in multiple tests for different objects.
I've tried to isolate these expects in a helper utility module before, but although there were intermediary mentions of failed expects half way, these tests didn't actually indicate failure at the end.

What is the better way to achieve the desired result?

Comment: Can't you just put them in a function, with an object parameter for the expect cases?

Comment: What @Lissy commented is what I would suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap them in a function.

```
function validateSavedUser(savedUser) {
  expect(savedUser).to.have.all.keys(['fbId', 'fbName', 'gender', 'birthdate', 'aboutMe']);
  expect(savedUser.fbId).to.equal(u.fbId);
  expect(savedUser.fbName).to.equal(u.fbName);
  expect(savedUser.gender).to.equal(u.gender);
  expect(savedUser.birthdate).to.equal(u.birthdate);
  expect(savedUser.aboutMe).to.equal(u.aboutMe);
}
```

Comment: This is what I tried before, but adding it to a separate module. I.e. `exports.validateSavedUser = (savedUser) => {...}` but this didn't indicate that the actual test failed at the end (`ìt( ... )`). I'll try again after diner.

Comment: Did you import expect into the module? This should work.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I've been busy with some code refactoring. It works after all, not sure what went wrong before.

Comment: Actually I know what was the problem. The test itself used an asynchronous function for retrieving the decoded value of a jwt. Using `await` showed the failed test as expected.